# how to filter facebook response from graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

im trying to access the posts of a public facebook page. Im getting all the unwanted stuff such a comments and likes, is it possbile to filter the data through url so that i can get only the posts written by the user?
im using this url to access:
https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXX?access_token=XXXXX&fields=name,likes,feed

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/feed

Answer (score 0):

try {page_ID}/posts?fields=from

and you can filter the result by using Javascript Script.